# Building an extremely simple auth system in ember.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js

I'm trying to develop an extremely simple auth system in Ember.js 1.5 but I am having some trouble for the front-end part.

I am very new to ember so please excuse my ignorance.

So here are my routes and their implementations

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login');
    this.resource("posts");

});

App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (Ember.isEmpty(App.Auth.get('authToken'))) {
            this.transitionTo('login');
        }
    }
});

App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('login_template');
    },
    actions: {
        createSession: function() {
            var router = this;
            var email = this.controller.get('email_login');
            var password = this.controller.get('password_login');


            if (!Ember.isEmpty(email) && !Ember.isEmpty(password)) {


                $.post('/api/v1/session', {email: email, password: password}, function(data) {
                    var authToken = data.session.auth_token;
                    var user_id = data.session.user_id;

                    App.Store.authToken = authToken;
                    App.Auth = Ember.object.create({
                        authToken: authToken,
                        user_id: user_id
                    });

                    router.transitionTo('index');
                });



            }
        }
    }
});

App.ApplicationRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('post');
    }

});

App.ProceduresRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.all('post');
    }
});


// Ommitting the models because they aren't necessary for this question
```

So the main concern of course is that `App.Auth` is initially undefined. I've copied most of the code from a tutorial and I don't know if ember has any `session variables` that I can initialize.

In any case, I can always just define `App.Auth` at the beginning with initial values of null for it's properties but that might have other consequences that I am not aware of (again I am new to ember).

So my question here is that how can I properly store the response from the server (auth_token and user_id) in a nice manner. Also, have the user redirected to the `login` route if `auth_token` is not set (which is what I am trying to do with the authenticated route part).

You do not need to provide a full answer if you cannot, even some tips / comments will be extremely helpful, thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by nice manner?  Is there some particular problem you  are facing beside a null object reference?  `Ember.isEmpty(Ember.get(App, 'Auth'))`

Comment: By nice manner I meant, how to avoid this `null` issue plus going with ember's best practices in storing things like this.

Comment: Will I be able to access the Auth variable else where in the application like other controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use the container to register an auth manager, and inject it into everything.

```
App.initializer({
    name: "auth",
    before: ['ember-data'],
    initialize: function (container, application) {
       var auth = Ember.Object.extend({
         isAuthenticated: Em.computed.notEmpty('authToken')
       });

      application.register("my:authToken", auth);
      application.inject("controller", "auth", "my:authToken");
      application.inject("route", "auth", "my:authToken");
      application.inject("store:main", "auth", "my:authToken");
      application.inject("adapter", "auth", "my:authToken");
    }
});
```

Then on your adapter you could hook up headers easily (if needed)

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: function() {
    return {
      authToken: this.get('auth.authToken')
    };
  }.property("auth.authToken")
});
```

From any controller/route you could easily access the auth property from `this.auth`

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        if (!this.auth.get('isAuthenticated')) {
            this.transitionTo('login');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's an example with the injection (note, I'm using Ember Data 1.0 beta 8, some of this functionality, the headers, isn't available in older versions of Ember Data).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/639/edit

Comment: I need to be able to get and set autoToken as well as user_id

So first question is how do I set authToken/user_id in my login route's action method?

Is it as simple as `this.auth.set('authToken')`?

Comment: Which doesn't seem to work, especially in the login route. The error `auth` is undefined pops up when trying to set the `authToken`;

Comment: this.auth.set('authToken', 'foo'), and it looks like it works fine, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/648/edit ,  Are you sure you're in scope of the route/controller, and not in the scope of a returned ajax call?

Comment: I am in the scope of a returned ajax call. That's where the data is coming from. I am not sure how i'd be able to set the authToken else where.

Comment: Add a reference to this, then use that reference in the callback.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/652/edit

Comment: what about user_id, how can I have it added just like how authToken is added?

Comment: the exact same way, `self.auth.set('user_id', response.user_id);`